# Windows Live Mail, Sec. Exception on an Account

Tags: email, certificate, windows-live-mail

I have one email account that have a unaccepted certificate.
The Thunderbird, and Opera can handle this with a Security Exception.

But Windows Live Mail ask a question in every starting, and because this is not modal form, many times I forget to answer with Yes - and my mails are never sent, because the WLM waits for this answer...

This is very disturbing thing, so I want to find some menupoint, or option to disable checking this account, or add an Exception to certificates...

Please send me an info, how to do it?

Thanks:
   dd

---

This is hungarian Windows, so I try to re-translate the message:

The server you connected is uses a certificate that cannot be checked.
The processing of the certificate-chain finished, but the main certificate is not trustable by the trust-checker.

Do you want to use this server?

Comment: Some more info about what are the exact error messages and what's wrong with the certificate is required first.

Comment: I added the info I got.